# ERROR IN PYTHON: TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U4') dtype('<U4') dtype('<U4')

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I run this code in python

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as networkFile:
    for line in networkFile:
            src = line.split()[0]
            nodes.append(src)
nodesf = np.unique(nodes)

with open("test.txt", "r") as networkFile:
    for line in networkFile:
            src = line.split()[0]
            network.append([src])
edgesf = np.array(network)

avgDegree = (2 * edgesf) / nodesf
print("avgDegree: ",avgDegree)
```

and give me error in a line     `avgDegree = (2 * edgesf) / nodesf`

```
TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types   
`dtype('<U4') dtype('<U4') dtype('<U4')`
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why are you making arrays of strings? Why are you making arrays at all? It looks like you want to count the number of edges and nodes, not make arrays.

Comment: Did you even bother to look at `edgesf` and `nodesf` to see what they contain?  At the very least check the `dtype` (I'd also verify the `shape`).  Don't assume intermediate steps in your code work.  Test them, step by step if needed.